# Android Studio /dev/kvm is missing

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

I just installed Android Studio and is getting an error /dev/kvm whenever i add a virtual device in my pc.

OS: Win 7 64bit

- Intel virtualization is already enabled in BIOS. Already re-enabled but still the same
- Uninstalled HAXM and reinstalled it from Android Studio.
- Uninstalled HAXM and installed it from INTEL website. Got configuration error.

Comment: Hi @JonathonReinhart. Does that mean I installed the wrong version of Android Studio in my computer?

Answer (score 1):

**Follow this instruction:**

1.Check if you have download and installed "intell x86 emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)"

2.Check if "Hardware Virtualization " is enabled in BIOS. If not, enable it, i have already enbled it.

3.Go to your sdk folder, extras--> intel --> Hardware_Accelerate_execution_manager-->install "intellhaxm-android.exe"

Comment: I cant seem to install the intelhaxm-android.exe even with the workaround. it says failed to configure driver intel haxm